# Why is the spacing between titles usually set to equal length?

Tags: text, page-layout, paragraph-styles

In text editors, html, etc. the default mode of sub title spacing seems to quite equal. Why is that?

To clarify, we have an end paragraph of a subsection and a new subsection with title and opening paragraph. Looking like this:

p1

h3

p2

Now the spacing between p1 and h3, and, h3 and p2 is usually by default equal or near to equal. Why is that? Is there some typography lesson to be had? To me it just looks plain wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Why is leading always set to 120% in applications? Some value needs to be used and the most common denominator is probably the best option from an app development standpoint.

It's generally understood that defaults are defaults and should/will be changed.

If you're dealing with HTML, that's what CSS reset libraries are for - to remove defaults forcing you to address each text block. Which you should be doing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The 'typography lesson' here is called 'vertical rhythm'. If the baselines of all of your text align to the same grid, the layout is calm on the eyes and easier to read. It for this reason that layout software has a 'baseline grid' function, and why standard html does it as well.

In 'Grid design', you align all your elements to both a vertical and horizontal grid, to create this clean and easy look. It's gotten some discussion the last few years, especially online.